# Measure Angular Partial Rendering Performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, partial-views

Is it possible to somehow measure a http call to render a partial?

In my application, even though the partial is always present, the call to render it sometimes fails or takes a lot longer than usual, despite the fact that nothing has changed.

Is there a way to measure the call to render so it can somehow be optimised or improved?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ui-router`you will have `$viewContentLoaded` event. This event triggered for every `view` that done loading at current page. So measuring will be between `resolve` or `Controller` constructor function and `$viewContentLoaded` event.

When I was faced such problem I replaced a lot of `ng-view` with `ng-include` and that solved my problem.